# Returning maximum number of users attached to a particular ClientID in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having a database table named traveller_info in SQL where I have columns like:

- ID
- Name
- City
- Pnr_No etc.

I want to display the **Pnr_No** that has the maximum number of users by using column **ID**.
The query should display **Pnr_No** and Total_Users associated with that **Pnr_No**.

I think I need to use the subqueries to achieve this. I am doing this way but it is not displaying the correct Total.

```
SELECT Pnr_No , COUNT(ID)Total from traveller_info 
WHERE ID in (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM traveller_info )
Group by Pnr_No
```

I will be glad to have your help to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TRY THIS**: You can simply do it without using `sub-query`

```
SELECT TOP 1 Pnr_No , COUNT(id) Tot 
FROM traveller_info 
GROUP BY Pnr_No 
ORDER BY Tot DESC
```

Comment: It was awesome. Thank you very much, sir.

Comment: @AshutoshSingh . . . You may want `top (1) with ties`, to get all numbers with the maximum count.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for this new thing sir. This is an absolutely new topic for me. Very helpful.